# How do I add a name alongside the score of a user in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

My program is a quiz that adds up the scores of a quiz and outputs the total score highest to lowest. However, the name of the user doesn't pop up in the score. Is there a way I could implement the user name to their score aswell. The variable that holds the user name is 'userName'.

```
newrecord = "{score_1},{score_2},{score_3}\n".format(score_1=quiz_scores[0], score_2=quiz_scores[1], score_3=quiz_scores[2])

classa = input("What class are you in? ")

if classa =='1':
    file=open('class 4.csv', "a+")
    file.write(newrecord)
    file.close()
if classa =='1':
with open('class 4.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    srt = sorted((sum(map(int,row)) for row in readCSV), reverse=True)
print(srt)
```

The outcome would be something like this, [24,20,16,18,17,12] etc. 
However, I would like it to also output the user name, for example, [James 24, Bob 20, Jane 16]

Answer (score 1):

Add `userName` to the beginning of the record and in the generator comprehension return a tuple of `(userName, score)`:

```
newrecord = "{user_name},{score_1},{score_2},{score_3}\n".format(user_name=userName, score_1=quiz_scores[0], score_2=quiz_scores[1], score_3=quiz_scores[2])

classa = input("What class are you in? ")

if classa =='1':
    file=open('class 4.csv', "a+")
    file.write(newrecord)
    file.close()

with open('class 4.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    srt = sorted(((row[0], sum(map(int,row[1:]))) for row in readCSV), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

print(srt)
```

Comment: Thanks. If I wanted to create a new csv file that is completely empty how would I do that? Because if I change this to file=open('class 5.csv') I will get an error that this file doesn't exist.

Comment: opening it in 'a' mode does create a file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: it would be a better idea to use csv.writer instead of writing it manually as it takes care of escaping. But since you used this i didn't want to change it.

Comment: How would I use csv.writer to create a file?

Comment: You wouldnt use it to create a file, but to write to it rather than using format and then writing a string.